# Capistrano login Net::SSH failure

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

Suddenly, Capistrano began to return a SSH issue:

> ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: staging.myserver.com
>   (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root) connection failed for:
>   staging.myserver.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)

My deploy.rb contains:

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:keys] = ["myserver_rsa"]

set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :scm, "git"
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:project/myapp.git"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

and at my config/deploy/staging.rb

```
server 'staging.myserver.com', :app, :web, :db, primary: true

set :branch, 'staging'
set :rails_env, "staging"

set :deploy_to, "/var/rails/#{application}"
set :user, "root"
set :password, "my_triple_check_password_login"
set :domain, "staging.myserver.com"
```

Tests made by me before posting here:

1. Try to login via ssh (ssh -v staging.myserver.com)
   => Logged successfully without prompt my password. (using myserver_rsa key)
2. Agent Forward
   => Enabled in server and in local
3. Try to login via ssh without keys:
   => prompted for password. Copy and paste it from staging.rb and logged perfectly.
4. Change server root password. => Try to login with new password via ssh root@... worked nice. but via capistrano, fails.
5. Run in IRB a Net SSH script to login.
   => Logged in and return a `hostname` result from bash.

This issue starts yesterday suddenly. I really don't have more ideas :/

First of all, nothing was change at server either Cap deploy configs.

Thanks!

Comment: how did you enable agent forwarding?

Comment: @phoet yes. In both sides. The stange part is: worked until yesterday without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found!

In my `/etc/ssh_config` root section I had:

```
Host *
     SendEnv LANG LC_*
     XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
     ForwardAgent yes
     PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I was need to create a section to my staging environment:

```
   Host staging.myserver.com
     IdentityFile /Users/hlegius/.ssh/myserver_rsa
     ForwardAgent yes
     RSAAuthentication no
     PasswordAuthentication no
```

and edit my `config/deploy.rb` to add: `default_run_options[:pty] = true`

Aaaaaaaaand it's works!

Comment: @hlegius 'm having the same error. But surprisingly this is not working for me. Any idea?

Comment: @nish Can you just ssh to your server and see it works or not. May be The server blocking you to get in.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the authentication failure. Capistrano can't connect to the deploying server with given username and password. I already done the deployment for a server and I am now deploying to a New server. Then I got this error.

It prompted me to give the password for new server. I entered the new server password. But its showing this error.

I changed the domain here

```
set :domain, "my-new-ip-or-domain"   => my new server domain
```

But forgot to change the username here in my deploy.rb

```
set :user, "my-new-username"
```

After giving the correct username and password it works perfectly!