# Unable to restart unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am trying to restart unicorn using the command `RUBBER_ENV=staging FILTER=staging cap rubber:unicorn:restart` but I'm getting the following error:

```
triggering load callbacks
* 2013-10-21 11:49:47 executing `rubber:init'
** Auto role: app => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: unicorn => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: nginx => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: collectd => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: common => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: monit => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: db => staging.x.com, {:primary=>true, :platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: postgresql => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: postgresql_master => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: examples => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: graphite_server => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: graphite_web => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: memcached => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: web => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
** Auto role: web_tools => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}
 * 2013-10-21 11:49:50 executing `rubber:unicorn:restart'
 * 2013-10-21 11:49:50 executing `rubber:unicorn:stop'
 * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'if [ -f /var/run/unicorn.pid ]; then pid=`cat /var/run/unicorn.pid` && kill -TERM $pid; fi'"
servers: ["staging.voylla.com"]
connection failed for: staging.x.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)
```

Some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363003/amazon-aws-cap-deploycheck-fails/15375167#15375167) ponted out a few things but I'm getting the error even after having the following set in my `deploy.rb`:

```
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/voylla.pem"]}
```

I even tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460364/capistrano-login-netssh-failure). But this doesn't work either.

Could someone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `** Auto role: web_tools => staging.x.com, {:platform=>"linux"}` is doing it not part os Capistrano.

The problem is that `sudo` is not able to change to your superuser account without a password, so you are being prompted. In Capistrano 2.x you can see the prompt, but there's no way to answer it (i.e anything you type is just sent nowhere due to a weirdness with how input handling works)

My suggested fix would be to make sure that your deploy user can call `sudo` without requiring a password, or change your script so that there's a `setuid` script you can call that encapsulates this logic.

Comment: I did `sudo visudo` and added the line `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` at the bottom as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password). But it didn't work. I'm getting the same error

Comment: If what you did had worked, the error would at least change, as ` * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash` wouldn't be printed anymore.

Comment: I checked using `sudo su`. its not prompting for password. So i guess I'm missing something else here

Comment: At this point you'd need to update your question with more information before I could help you. Of course the two lines `set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}; set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/voylla.pem"]}` might yet be the problem.

Comment: I just had to place the .pem file in the `~/.ssh` folder and do an `ssh-add` on it and it worked :). It works even after commenting out the two `set :ssh_options` lines.

Answer (score 0):

add the .pem file to the `~/.ssh` folder and then do an `ssh-add` on the .pem file